# GeeXbox ls shows no date?

Tags: shell, ls

Recently, I tried connecting to my GeeXbox via WinSCP but got an error indicating the output of `ls` could not be parsed.

Apparently, my `ls` does not include a time stamp! What might be the cause and how can I correct that? See a sample output below:

```
$ ls -la
total 96
drwxrwxr-x   17 root     root          4096 .
drwxrwxr-x   17 root     root          4096 ..
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 bin -> usr/bin
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     root         39779 config
drwxr-xr-x   13 root     root          3980 dev
drwxrwxr-x   29 root     root          4096 etc
```

My particular `ls --help` offers this:

```
$ ls --help
BusyBox v1.23.0.git (2014-05-19 13:33:13 IDT) multi-call binary.

Usage: ls [-1AaCxdlinshrSXv] [-w WIDTH] [FILE]...

List directory contents

    -1      One column output
    -a      Include entries which start with .
    -A      Like -a, but exclude . and ..
    -C      List by columns
    -x      List by lines
    -d      List directory entries instead of contents
    -l      Long listing format
    -i      List inode numbers
    -n      List numeric UIDs and GIDs instead of names
    -s      List allocated blocks
    -h      List sizes in human readable format (1K 243M 2G)
    -r      Sort in reverse order
    -S      Sort by size
    -X      Sort by extension
    -v      Sort by version
    -w N    Assume the terminal is N columns wide
    --color[={always,never,auto}]   Control coloring
```

Comment: And that's, dear children, why you're not supposed to parse the output of `ls`, different implementations, different output. Does `ls --help` give you an option to add the timestamp to the output?

Comment: @Bobby: see my edit

Comment: It may have something to do with terminal width or tabstops. You might want to try the `-w` option. The reason you get the complaint is your `Busybox` is not POSIX compliant. The output of `ls -l` is POSIX specified to be `"%s %u %s %s %u %s %s\n", <file mode>, <number of links>,
    <owner name>, <group name>, <number of bytes in the file>,
    <date and time>, <pathname>
` You can look at http://www.busybox.net/BusyBox.html which says `busybox ls` should also have a `-e` for full date and time.,

Answer (score 1):

Often times systems that are a "dedicated appliance" will make use of a tool called BusyBox. You can read more about the [BusyBox project](http://www.busybox.net/), but in a nutshell this project provides stripped down versions of typical tools such as `ls`, etc.

On my installations of XBMC that also use BusyBox the version of `ls` does show the the timestamp info when I do an `ls -l`. There's also an additional switch `-e` which will produce time date info.

```
# ls --help
BusyBox v1.21.0 (2013-01-22 19:16:54 CET) multi-call binary.

Usage: ls [-1AaCxdLHRFplinsehrSXvctu] [-w WIDTH] [FILE]...

List directory contents

    -1  One column output
    -a  Include entries which start with .
    -A  Like -a, but exclude . and ..
    -C  List by columns
    -x  List by lines
    -d  List directory entries instead of contents
    -L  Follow symlinks
    -H  Follow symlinks on command line
    -R  Recurse
    -p  Append / to dir entries
    -F  Append indicator (one of */=@|) to entries
    -l  Long listing format
    -i  List inode numbers
    -n  List numeric UIDs and GIDs instead of names
    -s  List allocated blocks
    -e  List full date and time
    -h  List sizes in human readable format (1K 243M 2G)
    -r  Sort in reverse order
    -S  Sort by size
    -X  Sort by extension
    -v  Sort by version
    -c  With -l: sort by ctime
    -t  With -l: sort by mtime
    -u  With -l: sort by atime
    -w N    Assume the terminal is N columns wide
    --color[={always,never,auto}]   Control coloring
```

So I would assume that you're encountering 1 of 2 situations.

1. Your version of BusyBox doesn't include timestamps in the `-l` output. I doubt this is the case, BTW.
2. The filesystem has timestamp tracking disabled via a `mount` option, due to the overhead involved with having to track this info.

There are options such as `noatime` which will disable the tracking of access time on the file system, for example.

```
$ mount -v
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /flash type vfat (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
```

Comment: I think it's problem #1. Look at his `--help` - there's no *sort by ?time* of any kind. What utility checks `mount` options before offering `--help` ?

Comment: @mikeserv - With #1 I just think it's highly unusual that a version of BusyBox would omit the timestamp. Just my $0.02 on that one 8-). No tool I'm aware of would look at mounts options, per say, but the tools might know how to deal with data that isn't present in the output. `stat` would likely be doing the same thing here.

Comment: Totally agreed - completely unusual. That's why WinSCP is able to rely on parsing that data. Somebody just built Busybox all crazy.

Comment: Sorry man. I forgot to do that before.